# Flutter Build Error (Cloned project from github)

Tags: flutter, dart

this the error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutterSDK\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutterSDK\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 34s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please include your '...flutter.gradle' file for identifying errors.

Comment: Also, you can use the `--debug` and `--stacktrace` flag, as instructed.